# Timer Trigger with Azure Functions V3 (.NET 5)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, .net-5

I am using .NET 5 and developing Azure Functions. When adding a new Timer Trigger function through Visual Studio it adds a file with this content:

```cs
public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        }
    }
```

I'm including it as a photo here to highlight that it doesn't compile because the TimerTrigger class doesn't exist.

Intellisense suggests that I add the following using:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
```

But that doesn't make sense, because that belongs to the previous version of Azure Functions. And sure enough, Intellisense detects this and show this error.

[image]

So how do I use TimerTrigger in .NET 5?

Maybe because this is relatively new, there seems to be no documentation or popular posts about this yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer` package, as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#extension-packages):

> Because functions that run in a .NET isolated process use different binding types, they require a unique set of binding extension packages.

> You'll find these extension packages under Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.

[Direct link to NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions)

Comment: That did the trick. I had to install this package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer/

Comment: WARNING: When I added the TimerTrigger, my function could no longer run locally. After removing it, I was able to run it again locally. I tried restarting VS and the whole computer to no avail so quite sure its the TimerTrigger.

Comment: Did you install the latest SDK from https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools?

Comment: No, but I assume Visual Studio takes care of this when I open it. Usually does.

Comment: Afaik not for the core and 5.0 version, so I recommend you check it out.

Comment: I had 3.0.3442 and upgraded to 3.0.3477 and it looks like it is working. Seems a little incomplete developer experience if I have to check for the latest version manually or when there are some more or less subtle issues that occur.

Comment: Actually it is still failing. It happens when the TimerTrigger is "PastDue" when starting up, then it locks up and never properly starts and then crashes or freezes up for a few minutes, then it closes.

Comment: I guess it is then time to [open an issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues). Actually, it looks like [this one](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/534)?

Comment: Yes you are right - and your original answer in this question remains true, before and after they fix this issue. I am just in disbelief that they could not catch something like this before unleashing it unto the world.

Comment: I have the same issue when add time trigger with Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer, this resolves the compiler issue, but then the azure never can be run from VS which always freezes like deadlock and the azure function work output timeout error

Answer (score 1):

I had also trouble with running timer trigger when migrating from .Net Core to .NET 5. Following attention points:

1. Migration of the project file to use .net 5 runtime
2. Adding Nuget Packages
3. Amendment of the local host json to use the correct function worker
4. Avoid using CancellationToken since it isn't provided any longer.

(1) Project File:

```
- [TargetFramework]net5.0[/TargetFramework]
- [AzureFunctionsVersion]v3[/AzureFunctionsVersion]
- [OutputType]Exe[/OutputType]
```

(2) Nuget References Required:

```
- "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.0.1"
- "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.3.0"
- "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.6.0"
```

(3)

```
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
```

Test timer trigger function:

```
public static class Function2
    {
        [Function("Function2")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] MyInfo myTimer, FunctionContext context)
        {
            var logger = context.GetLogger("Function2");
            logger.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            logger.LogInformation($"Next timer schedule at: {myTimer.ScheduleStatus.Next}");
        }
    }

    public class MyInfo
    {
        public MyScheduleStatus ScheduleStatus { get; set; }

        public bool IsPastDue { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyScheduleStatus
    {
        public DateTime Last { get; set; }

        public DateTime Next { get; set; }

        public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    }
```